# How can I use \dolistloop from etoolbox with \do redefined in preamble?

Tags: loops, etoolbox, preamble

I am trying to use `\dolistloop` from `etoolbox` with the `\do`-command redefined in the preamble. However, the redefinition of the `\do`-command is ignored. If I put it within the document, it works as expected. Here is the example that does not work as intended:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\alist}{}
\listadd{\alist}{Parrot}
\listadd{\alist}{Canary}

\def\birdlist{}

\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{
\appto\birdlist{Bird: #1. }
}

\begin{document}

\dolistloop{\alist}
\birdlist

\end{document}
```

The output of that code is: ParrotCanary, indicating that `\do` has not been redefined. If I move the redefinition of `\do` into the document,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\alist}{}
\listadd{\alist}{Parrot}
\listadd{\alist}{Canary}

\def\birdlist{}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{
\appto\birdlist{Bird: #1. }
}
\dolistloop{\alist}
\birdlist

\end{document}
```

the result is the expected: Bird: Parrot. Bird: Canary. How can I use the `\dolistloop` function with a `\do`-function that is defined in the preamble? (I am working on a project with documents in several subfolders and I want to avoid appending the `\renewcommand*{\do}`-code in each folder's `.tex`-files.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can't, at least not this way. `\do` is redefined in `\begin{document}` to be `\noexpand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend using `\dolistloop` in a global context: `\do` is a macro that is often redefined, especially in `\begin{document}` (or in `\AtBeginDocument{...}` in which it gets the meaning of `\noexpand`. I also would not use it 'globally' inside `\begin{document}`.

I suggest to use `\forlistloop` which requires a handler, but even this can be simplified (see the code)

Rename the personal definition of `\do`  into, say, `\dothis` and call `\forlistloop{\dothis}{\alist}` instead

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\alist}{}
\listadd{\alist}{Parrot}
\listadd{\alist}{Canary}

\newcommand{\birdlist}{}

\newcommand*{\dothis}[1]{%
\appto\birdlist{Bird: #1. }
}

%Define a wrapper
\newcommand{\fakedolistloop}[1]{%
  \forlistloop{\dothis}{#1}%
}

\fakedolistloop{\alist}

% Or call it directly

%\forlistloop{\dothis}{\alist}
\birdlist

\end{document}
```

[image]

**The inevitable `expl3` solution**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_rasmus_bird_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\addbird}{+m}{
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_rasmus_bird_seq {##1}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\listloop}{}{
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_rasmus_bird_seq {\dothis{##1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addbird{Parrot,Canary}
\addbird{Dead Parrot,Pantomime Goose}

\newcommand{\birdlist}{}

\newcommand*{\dothis}[1]{%
\appto\birdlist{Bird: #1. }
}

\begin{document}
\listloop


\birdlist
\end{document}
```

**Next installment**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\alist}{}
\listadd{\alist}{Parrot}
\listadd{\alist}{Canary}

\newcommand{\birdlist}{}

\newcommand*{\dothis}[2]{%
  \appto{#1}{Bird: #2. }
}

\newcommand{\fakedolistloop}[2]{%
  \forlistloop{\dothis{#2}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\otherbirdlist}{}
\fakedolistloop{\alist}{\birdlist}
\listadd{\alist}{Sparrow}

\fakedolistloop{\alist}{\otherbirdlist}

Showing:

\birdlist

or

\otherbirdlist
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works. Much appreciated. Would it be a possible to add the list to which we are appending, i.e \birdlist, as an argument to the loop-function? That would add flexibility to the usage of the command.

Comment: @Rasmus: Do you mean `\fakelistloop{\alist}{\birdlist}`?

Comment: @Rasmus: See the 3rd. version at the end -- did you mean that?

Comment: Ah :-) Great. But I am not sure I understand why that works. It seems that \fakelistloop only takes one argument?

Comment: It seemed to work also in the case where \fakelistloop was defined with only one argument. Which confused me a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `\do` that way. It's a scratch macro and you should redefine it at point of usage, as its meaning cannot be relied upon.

A different implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listadd}{mm}
 {
  \rasmus_list_add:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listmap}{m+m}
 {
  % define the scratch macro based on the second argument
  \cs_set:Nn \__rasmus_list_do:n { #2 }
  % map the list using the newly defined macro
  \seq_map_function:cN { g_rasmus_list_#1_seq } \__rasmus_list_do:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rasmus_list_add:nn
 {
  % make sure the list exists
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g_rasmus_list_#1_seq }
   {
    \seq_new:c  { g_rasmus_list_#1_seq }
   }
  % add the items
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn  { g_rasmus_list_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listadd{alist}{Parrot,Canary}

\listmap{alist}{%
  \listadd{birdlist}{Bird: #1.}%
}

\listmap{birdlist}{#1\par}

\end{document}
```

You can add items sequentially or also as a comma separated list, so

```
\listadd{alist}{Parrot,Canary}
```

and

```
\listadd{alist}{Parrot}
\listadd{alist}{Canary}
```

are equivalent.

As you see, you can use `\listmap` for different purposes, here for populating a new list and for printing the new list. The current item in the list is simply denoted by `#1`.

The trick is to redefine a scratch macro ourselves at point of use.

[image]

Comment: That works, although I must confess that the syntax is a little cumbersome for a novice.

Comment: @Rasmus It's a whole new world. :-)